# How to find platform/version string for compiled Python modules?

Tags: python, binding, swig, platform, abi

I'm using [swig](http://swig.org/) to generate Python-bindings to a C++ project. This gives me a file like `_libdivvun.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` on one machine, `_libdivvun.cpython-3.5m.so` on another, or even `_libdivvun.cpython-35m-darwin.so` on that same machine with a different Python version. For testing and packaging for multiple platforms, I'd like to be able to get the string after `_libdivvun` for a specific Python version – is there a "correct" way to do that? It doesn't seem like I can just use `$PYTHON --version` and `uname`, since e.g. the Python bundled with LibreOffice on the darwin platform doesn't include the `darwin` string (but has an extra dot in the Python version!).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/#proposal:

```
>>> sysconfig.get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX')
'.cpython-32mu.so'
>>> sysconfig.get_config_var('SOABI')
'cpython-32mu'
```